# JQuery loading image

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Is there any way to show a loading image while loading a image?

Comment: are you talking about the same image, or show another image while one is loading?

Comment: Show one image while loading loading another.

Comment: so you want a "loading" picture to show until real image fully loaded?

Comment: yes that is exaktly what i want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set a background image with css on the img element (or the containing element) - no javascript needed (you will, of course, need to set dimensions on the img tag)

If you want to ensure the image isnt displayed until fully loaded you can use [this technique.](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/)

Comment: That would not be 100% good solution as a modem user might see the image loading from top to bottom.

Comment: To overcome that, you would need to preload the image with javascript and then replace it. Theres an example here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/